# Performance of predicate on the length of a list

Tags: haskell

I have read (and also reasoned) that calculating the length of a list is not good for performance in Haskell. However, i have long lists in my program and my requirement is to find that if length is greater than or less than some number X.

Is their already something in build in Haskell for these kind of predicates ? or i have to resort to manual looping.

Comment: What do you mean by not good for performance ? It's O(n), but that's the inevitable.

Comment: my X << n, so i think that it should be doable in O(X) and not O(n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On vanilla lists, you can check this using `drop`:

```
cmpLen :: Int -> [a] -> Ordering
cmpLen n xs
    | n < 0     = GT
    | otherwise = case drop (n-1) xs of
        []  -> GT
        [_] -> EQ
        _   -> LT
```

However, this still takes as long as the *value* (not size, as is typical of asymptotic analysis!) of `n`. If you intend to do this often, you can take a cue from Okasaki and build a new structure that caches the operation you want to be efficient. I have wanted this a few times before, and found the following sort of interface convenient in those cases:

```
type LenList a = (Sum Word, [a])
singleton x = (1, [x])
cons x = (singleton x<>)
length = getSum . fst
elems  = snd
```

Note that, since `LenList a` is already a `Monoid`, you get some of the usual operations for free, e.g. there is an empty `LenList a` named `mempty`, and concatenation is given by `(<>)`. Some operations (notably the ones that produce infinite lists) will not be implementable for this type. However, you pay an O(1) price on each construction operation to make asking for the length of one of these O(1), which can be a nice tradeoff in many situations.

Comment: I am a haskell newbie.. chapter "input-output" in LYAH.. so not familiar with Monoid.. but is it like storing length with the list itself.?

Comment: @AshishNegi That's it exactly.